# Praying in this condition

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sexuality, parts-of-the-body

Some times, like just after waking-up, men have an erection. But what if one just woke up and wants to say the *Mode Ani*, must he wait for it to pass or can he say it as is? Would it be disrespectful or make an averah to say it as is?

Comment: If there is a strong urge to go to the bathroom upon waking, and yet one cannot pray while one must relieve himself, can he still say modeh ani? Is it a "prayer" in that sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gabe, I just saw the Ramban write* about the human body, and how no part of it should be considered disgusting or ugly. This part, according to him, is just the same as a hand or a foot or a nose. Hashem made it. The fact that one has an erection should make no difference to his saying Modeh Ani, as long as he is appropriately covered for tzniyut reasons.

*(I should clarify - I didn't actually see him write it, I saw an excerpt from what he wrote, in a sefer for Kallah teachers).

Comment: The Ramban did not write any sefer specifically intended for Kallah teachers. I imagine the notion didn't exist at the time, as daughters were Halachically educated by their parents. I suggest you provide a source, or reference as to which sefer you were quoting or what document this Ramban was cited in. -- This is aside for the fact that just because a body part isn't disgusting, doesn't mean it is permitted to pray in it's presence (such as Ervah).

Comment: @Chaim He didn't say the Ramban wrote a sefer for kallah teachers.

Answer (score 1):

modeh ani is said without washing ones hands when one is actually tamei. as soon as one wakes up in the morning the appropriate thing to do is to sit up and acknowledge the creator for returning your soul to you. this is done regardless of the state one is in. (tehilas Hashem annotated edition page 586 discuses saying modeh ani in a very bikitzur manner)

This is a great link... http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1466224/jewish/Modeh-Ani.htm

In regards to machshava zaras. There is a difference between a thought that was thinks of and that one thinks about. We don't have control over what we think of. Thoughts can come and go and are random through out the day. What we decide to focus on though is a choice. The response though is not to stop thinking about something but rather to redirect ones thoughts on something else all together. Once one is focuses on a different subject the previous machshava zara will be gone b/c by definition you are thinking of a different thing now.

Much hatzlacha in your avoda. As always more specifics about these topics can be learned about from a mashpia. Everyone needs a mashpia like it says in pirkei avos aseh lecha rav

Comment: How does this answer the OP?

Comment: part of the question was deleted and so part of my answer was for the part which was deleted. Modeh ani is said as soon as one wakes up regardless of one's condition. It is said even before washing one's hands. The point brought up in the question also doesn't matter one can and does say modeh ani first thing in the morning.

Comment: I hate when that happens - and I sometimes quote parts of the question into the answer, to prevent that.